# Multi Tenancy OAuth Resource Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I would like to build a multi-tenant OAuth2 Resource Server with Spring Boot (still 2.7).

Basically, my requests are of the form `server:port/tenant/...` so I have to resolve the relevant auth server from the request URL. I have found this article [article from spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html). The issue here is, that you have to provide a list of valid auth servers which are then all valid for any request - which is wrong in my case.

I have found the `ServerWebExchangeDelegatingReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver`, which is not documented at all. Its method signature seems to imply, it is possible to dynamically return a `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` instance depending on the request URL.

I am, however, unsure, how to generate the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` instance. I have taken a look at the predefined classes which do not seem to solve the issue "resolve JWT relative to a given issuer". Best bet seems to be the `JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager`, but this class only validates the JWT in itself, so any valid JWT is accepted and it is not verified, it came from the correct server.

I now see different possibilities to proceed.

1. Generate my own instance of the `ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver`
2. Use the `ServerWebExchangeDelegatingReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` and provide my own instance of the enclosed `ReactiveAuthenticationManager`
3. Use the default `JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager` and fumble my own `ReactiveJwtDecoder`

I think, all the paths my lead to an eventual success, but I am unsure, how it was meant to be done.

Any hints?

Comment: You could find [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_multitenant_dynamic) useful. It is a servlet, but adapting it to a reactive application is straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. While it is not the solution I am looking for, it helped me to get a working idea. I will elaborate on that one and assuming it works out, I will post it.